# Delayed messages in Outlook don't show up in the Sent Items folder until sent

Tags: microsoft-outlook, delay

I've set a delay in Outlook (2010) on all my outgoing mail (2 mins) which is working well. However, the messages don't appear in my sent items until after they send. This means I can't find them to cancel them if required. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Messages that have not been sent appear in your `Outbox`.  Once sent, they appear in your `Sent Items`

The act of cancelling a message is to send the recipient a Recall message for an already sent email - this is sometimes automatically honoured in internal networks, but otherwise is a request the end user can choose to honour or not.

In your case, if you don't want to send the message and realise this before the delay expires, then just delete it from your `Outbox`.

Answer (score 2):

I know what you mean by "cancel". You want to stop a delayed email from actually being transmitted while it is still sitting in the Outbox. This is not to be confused with *recalling* an email- which is something else entirely.

Remember this:

**"Outbox"** = *pending* outbound messages (either due to delayed send, or the fact it is simply still in the process of sending.) You *usually* only see an email in here for any length of time if large attachments slow it down slightly- then it moves to the Sent folder (unless using delayed send, when it becomes normal- as in this case).

**"Sent Items"** = *delivered* outbound messages. It's gone. The only option here would *attempting* a recall.

The "Sent" folder only tells you want has *already* been sent. So, if an email you sent isn't there, then it will still be in "outbox" and is likely still within your 2 minute delay window.

How can you make it easier to find these emails to cancel them?

Consider adding the "Outbox" folder to your "Favorites" list at the top, so you can always find it quickly if you suddenly change your mind about an email you "sent":

[image]

Comment: Oops. Thank you both for a very patient and helpful response given the question. In my defense (if there could possibly be one), my sent items was pinned to favorites and I seem to have generated two separate directories of folders- found the outbox hiding in a list of mostly unused folders at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

In the new Outlook Mac the scheduled sent items can be found in the "Drafts" folder. You're welcome.