# reschedule/edit outlook emails

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Please explain how to edit a scheduled email in outlook?
My email is already scheduled for next week. I need to cancel it or edit it and I can't find it. Mainly because I didn't save the original message.

Answer (score 0):

An email scheduled/delayed to be sent later should remain in Outlook until it's sent so you can edit/cancel it - it should be in your Outbox.

From Microsoft's "[Delay or schedule sending e-mail messages](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/outlook-help/delay-or-schedule-sending-e-mail-messages-HP001232817.aspx)":

> After you click Send, the message remains in the Outbox folder until the delivery time.

If you deleted it from your Outbox, then it's gone and won't be sent when the time comes.

Related SU question: [Delayed messages in Outlook don't show up in the Sent Items folder until sent](https://superuser.com/questions/560915/delayed-messages-in-outlook-dont-show-up-in-the-sent-items-folder-until-sent)